# How do i make an android app that can record and listen at the same time

Tags: android-studio, record, playback

I have trouble making an app that can record and listen at the same time. I have create a recorder that is able to record and play at the moment,but i would really appreciate if someone could give suggestion on how to get started with android studio so that i can make the app to record and listen at the same time.

```
    stop.setEnabled(false);
    play.setEnabled(false);
    outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myrec.3gp";

    myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
}

public void start(View v) {
    try {
        myAudioRecorder.prepare();
        myAudioRecorder.start();
    }catch (IllegalStateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    start.setEnabled(false);
    stop.setEnabled(true);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Recording started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void stop(View v) {
    myAudioRecorder.stop();
    myAudioRecorder.release();
    myAudioRecorder=null;
    stop.setEnabled(false);
    play.setEnabled(true);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Audio successfully recorded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
public void play(View v) throws IOException {
    MediaPlayer m=new MediaPlayer();
    m.setDataSource(outputFile);
    m.prepare();
    m.start();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

Comment: Could you share your code so far so that others can extend it?

Comment: I have added my code in mainactivity.java